# Problemas consumiendo api rest con angular 5

Tags: angular, api, rest

Tengo este interceptor y tengo un servicio

Interceptor

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpSentEvent, HttpHeaderResponse, HttpProgressEvent, HttpResponse, HttpUserEvent, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private router : Router){

    }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpProgressEvent | HttpResponse<any> | HttpUserEvent<any>> {

          if(!req.url.includes('oauth/token') && req.url.includes('pineapple-admin-core')){

              console.log('Si entro');
              let headers : any;

              if(localStorage.getItem('userToken')){
                  console.log(localStorage.getItem('userToken'));
                  headers = new HttpHeaders({
                      'Authorization' : 'Bearer '+ JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('userToken')), 
                      'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
                      'Accept' : 'application/json, text/plain, */*' 
                  });
              }
              const cloneReq = req.clone({headers});
              return next.handle(cloneReq);

          }else if(req.url.includes('oauth/token')){
            return next.handle(req.clone());
          }else{
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
          }
    }
}
```

Para el login me funciona bien , pero cuando hago una peticion get a otro servicio

Este es mi servicio

```
getUserMe(){
   return this.http.get(this.getMe).catch(this.handleError);
 }
```

Me da un 401 la petición , en la primera petición que es el OPTIONS , si le hago un resend a la petición y le pongo el token manual en la cabecera , la petición me da respuesta por lo que infiero que la en el interceptor no está seteando el token en el header , que puediera estar pasando , eso me tiene loco , muchas gracias por su ayuda